# Cochran-Armitage trend test in R

Tags: r, function, testing, group-by, p-value

I have data that looks like this :
(the encoding_0 , encoding_1, encoding_2 column are the the counts of how many time the encoding 0,1,2 happens for is_severe column for each value of snp_id :

```
 X            snp_id         is_severe encoding_1 encoding_2 encoding_0
1     0  GL000191.1-37698         0          0          1          7
2     1  GL000191.1-37698         1          0          2         11
3     3 GL000192.1-100085         0          5          3          0
4     4 GL000192.1-100085         1          3         10          0
```

i wish to perform Cochran-Armitage trend test when the binomial value is the is_severe column and the ordinal data (already in the frequency table ) are the columns:encoding_0 , encoding_1, encoding_2.
i found this function that performs the test :

```
   catt_2 <-
  function(y, x, score = c(0, 1, 2)) {
    miss <- unique(c(which(is.na(y)), which(is.na(x))))
    n.miss <- length(miss)
    if(n.miss > 0) {
      y <- y[-miss]
      x <- x[-miss]
    }
    if(!all((y == 0) | (y == 1))) 
      stop("y should be only 0 or 1.")
    if(!all((x == 0) | (x == 1) |(x == 2))) 
      stop("x should be only 0, 1 or 2.")
    ca <- x [y == 1]
    co <- x [y == 0]
    htca <- table(ca)
    htco <- table(co)
    A <- matrix(0, 2, 3)
    colnames(A) <- c(0, 1, 2)
    rownames(A) <- c(0, 1)
    A[1, names(htca)] <- htca
    A[2, names(htco)] <- htco
    ptt <- prop.trend.test(A[1, ], colSums(A), score = score)
    res <- list(
                chisq = as.numeric(ptt$statistic), 
                 
                p.value = as.numeric(ptt$p.value)
                )
    return(res)
  }
```

BUT the argument X is a vector that doesn't contain the frequencies but only the encoding type (0,1,2) and i already have the frequency table.
as i understand the calculation of frequencies and the performance of the test (using prop.trend.test -https://search.r-project.org/R/refmans/stats/html/prop.trend.test.html(
happens here:

```
htca <- table(ca)
        htco <- table(co)
        A <- matrix( 2, 2)
        colnames(A) <- c(1,2)
        rownames(A) <- c(0, 1)
        A[1, names(htca)] <- htca
        A[2, names(htco)] <- htco
        ptt <- prop.trend.test(A[1, ], colSums(A), score = score)
```

i was wondering if it is possible to change this function and adapt it to the situation when i already have the frequencies. ( i have to perform the function for every snp_id and for that im going to use the by() function )
I tried for example converting some data to a matrix :

```
  ï..is_severe encod_0 encod_1 encod_2
[1,]            0       1       2       5
[2,]            1       3       2       8
```

and then did :

```
prop.trend.test(my_mat,colSums(my_mat))
```

and it returned this:

```
prop.trend.test(my_mat,colSums(my_mat))
Error in model.frame.default(formula = freq ~ score, data = list(freq = x/n,  : 
  variable lengths differ (found for '(weights)')
```

thank you:)

Answer (score 0):

```
catt <-
  function(y, x0,x1,x2, score = c(0, 1, 2)) {
    h=data.frame(is_severe=c(0,1),
                 encod_0=c(0,0),
                 encod_1=c(0,0),
                 encod_2=c(0,0)
    )
    h$is_severe=y
    h$encod_0=x0
    h$encod_1=x1
    h$encod_2=x2
    my_mat <- as.matrix(h)
    A <- matrix(0, 2, 3)
    colnames(A) <- c(0, 1, 2)
    rownames(A) <- c(0, 1)
    A[1,] =my_mat[1,2:4]
    A[2, ]=my_mat[2,2:4]
    ptt <- prop.trend.test(A[1, ],colSums(A), score = score) 
    p.value = as.numeric(ptt$p.value) 
    res <- list(
      chisq = as.numeric(ptt$statistic), 
      
      p.value = as.numeric(ptt$p.value)
    )
    return(res)
  
    }
catt_2 <-
  function(y, score = c(0, 1, 2)) {
    
    A <-y
    colnames(A) <- c(0, 1, 2)
    rownames(A) <- c(0, 1)
    ptt <- prop.trend.test(A[1, ], colSums(A), score = score)
    res <- list("2x3-table"=A,
                chisq = as.numeric(ptt$statistic), 
                 
                p.value = as.numeric(ptt$p.value)
                )
    return(res)
  }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).